# How to crop images in React Native, so that it'll be like a circular shape instead of rectangle one?

Tags: javascript, react-native, image-processing

I do have some pictures, and I need to crop them in a circular shapes before using them in React Native to use as ViroImage in react-viro (a library that render 360Images).

I can not apply much styles to the pictures and the `borderRadius` doesn't seem to solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

create a container with border radius = 30 and then place your image inside it

Answer (score 1):

I've created [react-native-image-tools-wm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-tools-wm) library when I had to process an image on the client and couldn't find anything worth using. Try it.

Example:

```js
const image = Image.resolveAssetSource(require('./my-image.jpg)).uri;
const maskImage = Image.resolveAssetSource(require('./mask-image.png)).uri;

RNImageTools.mask(image, maskImage).then(({ uri, width, height }) => {
    // Sync with your app state
});
```

Please note that your mask image should be black on white on iOS and black on transparent on Android. Black part will be replaced with your image and white/transparent will become transparent. You can use .android and .ios suffix on names and RN will load them conditionally.

You can also create a mask using `createMaskFromShape` method but you'll have to generate shape points yourself.